# HTML Button NOT Displaying Javascript Coded Image Display

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, onclick

I have some javascript functionality that did work at one time, a few weeks ago, but wasn't crucial while I developed an application for my company, so I didn't notice when it seemed to simply stop working...but now it matters.  It's a button which, when clicked, should display an image below the button.  At present nothing happens when I click the button...though it used to properly display the image.

Here is the original code (in the head of the page):

```
function getImageFL()
{
 var x = document.getElementById("flacBtn").value;
 document.getElementById("flac_place").src=x;
}
```

And the the button tag (from the body of the page):

```
<button id="flacBtn" value="other_pages/images/flac.png" onclick="getImageFL()">Click for image of FLAC model</button><br>
<img id="flac_place" height="200" width="349" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Today I tried something else, for another button/image pair, but this doesn't seem to do anything either...the new code (also in head):

```
function getImageRW()
{
 var x = document.getElementById("rwBtn").value;
 var image = document.getElementById('rw_place');
 image.setAttribute('src', x);
 image.style.visibility='visible';
}
```

And in the button tag (in body):

```
<button id="rwBtn" value="other_pages/images/3D-3.png" onclick="getImageRW()">Click for image of RW model</button><br>
<img id="rw_place" height="170" width="425" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Any ideas why neither of these do a thing? And why the first one, at least, used to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first one wouldn't work as you forgot to set `visibility='visible';` on there

```
function getImageFL()
{
 var x = document.getElementById("flacBtn").value;
 document.getElementById("flac_place").src=x;
 document.getElementById("flac_place").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tTLf6/1/)**

The 2nd one works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tTLf6/

Comment: I see that it does work for you, as it did for me a few weeks ago. Any idea why it would stop working for me? I've tried it in Chrome, IE, and my main browser, Firefox...nothing.

Comment: I also have some javascript on the same page that shows a 'waiting' image while some processing occurs.  That too did work a couple of weeks ago and doesn't now...nor does some javascript that does some input checking...same story.  It's as if all of the javascript on this particular cgi-generated page ceased working, probably at the same time, but I didn't note when it did, as I was mainly concerned w/ getting the processing correct for the past couple of weeks. The page that precedes the cgi-generated page also has javascript on it which does continue to work correctly.

Comment: it could be many things... I suggest you use firebug and watch what happens to the element that's supposed to receive the image... by the way, any specific reason why you wouldn't just add the image with the src already there (if there are more, you could add all) hidden, and just show the one that is needed...? I think it would be faster too...